# connecting jenkins vm to github with webhook, Windows 10

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, port, github, jenkins

I have a Virtualbox guest VM running with Jenkins, in my Windows 10 host.

The VM is exposed through a bridge, and I can access it in my browser at my Wi-Fi interface ip address.

I have set up a webhook with github for automatic build triggering.

My problem is that Jenkins builds are not being triggered.

I analysed the http traffic between my host and github using wireshark. Github is definitely sending packets to my host machine and they are reaching the wi-fi interface address, but at the wrong port.

the Jenkins guest is at port 8080, while the packets are being sent to other ports.

Is there a way to make the incoming packets from github arrive at only port 8080? Is port forwarding required?

Comment: Have you tried putting the port number into the webhook url? `http://host.example.com:8080/pathname`